# Pascal - Whats causing this runtime error(216)?

Tags: pascal

Whenever I run `SafteyDepositBox.SetNewCode` I get a `runtime error 216`. Any idea whats causing this?
This is the error :

> Runtime error 216 at $00401EFC
>    $00401EFC
>    $0040153D
>   $00401596
>    $00406E31

```
program Boxy;
{$MODE OBJFPC}
{$M+}
type
 SDB = class
  private
   State : string;
   Code : string;
  public
   Constructor Create();
   procedure SetNewCode(newcode:string);
   function Valid(s:string):boolean;
end;

constructor SDB.Create();
begin
 State := 'Open-NoCode';
 Code := ''; 
end;

procedure SDB.SetNewCode(newcode:string);
begin
 Code := newcode;
 writeln(Code);
end;

function SDB.Valid(s:string):boolean;
var
 IsValid : boolean;
begin 
 If (length(s) = 4) then
  IsValid := true
 else
  IsValid := false;
 Valid := IsValid;
end;

var 
 SafetyDepositBox : SDB;
begin
 SafetyDepositBox.Create();
 SafetyDepositBox.SetNewCode('r2d2');// runtime error 216 here
end.
```

Comment: See this question asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064576/pascal-access-violation-when-calling-a-variable-in-a-class

Comment: You could also compile with the `-gp -gl` FPC options to get a bit more help rather than a raw stack dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG you just made me remember Pascal!

This is how you call the object constructor:

```
SafetyDepositBox := SDB.Create();
```

Comment: Ikr. I'm a C# coder myself. This is just for school stuff.